Error in Hyperledger Fabric when invoking the chaincode on my network
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction c0afc04f0a9fb66b6cba1af268331d1fa6708284b678dca71da0b30251099564: could not launch chaincode basic_1.0:8f82417623cf8692d70e9c0e75cc797fa5da04eb3f7f37aac9578932a8b0f937: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 127" .
Does anyone know how to solve it? Because at first it was giving me an error code 1, and now it's giving me 127, but I can't fix it.
I've created a network in Hyperledger Fabric, and when I try to invoke my chaincode written in JavaScript, I encounter this issue
